# How do they checks for vulnerabilities on Apple Store application?

Tags: security, app-store

I know that when you submit an application for Apple Store, it gets tested: if they find a vulnerability the application gets reject.

How do they do this checking? How accurate is it? What vulnerabilities are most likely to get accepted, fooling the test?

Comment: Are you looking for a way to hide a purposeful vulnerability in your app?

Comment: I dont know I am pretty sure you cant get away with most stuff. Sometimes they let you have your app description over the limit other than that who knows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple isn't the only one,  Mozilla also does [this for their add-ons](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/policies/reviews).   In both cases,  its a mix of developers reading though the code aided by [static code analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_code_analysis).